# Convert text data to a numeric value to use in a multiplication

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate the product of three cells but one of the cells is a dropdown which contains text:

`B2*C2*D2` (D2 is text)

I would like `D2` to be converted as follows:

`SELECT` → `0`

`NO` → `0`

`YES` → `1`

So I tried

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B2:D2,{"SELECT","NO","YES"})*{B2*C2*0,B2*C2*0,B2*C2*1})
```

but this formula is not working.

How could this be done?

Comment: `=B2*C2*IF(D2="YES",1,0)`.

Comment: @Akina Although I prefer (the hackier) `=B2*C2*(D2="YES")`. Yep, I *definitely* like the looks of mine better ;-)  Far easier to read!

Comment: @robinCTS This is not documeted, it seems? I avoid those techniques in most cases... it can produce version incompatibility.

Comment: @Akina Actually it is well documented. Booleans are implicitly cast by Excel to numbers when required, `TRUE` → 1 and `FALSE` → 0. Has always been like that, and always will be. (It would break too many things to change it, and there is no reason why a change would be required )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolutely, positively, definitely, shortest way of doing so is:

```dart
=B2*C2*(D2="YES")
```

There's no more to say.

Comment: Great use of a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

*You can try this simple IF Else formula:*

```
=IF(D2="Select",(B2*C2*0),IF(D2="NO",(B2*C2*0),IF(D2="Yes",(B2*C2*1))))
```

This formula will test all three values in D2 then calculate accordingly.